# Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 - glTFLoader in Three.js and Vue app

Tags: json, vue.js, three.js, gltf

I want to load a .glTF file into three.js using the GLTFLoader in my Vue app. However, I continue to get this error in the console when I try to load the .gltf file with the GLTFLoader:

`Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`

I have instantiated both Three.js and the GLTFLoader inside a Vue.js component.

After some research, I can see this is because the HTTP request for the glTF asset returns a HTML site. I have checked the network response and 'modeltest.gltf' content type is 'text/html'.

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Status Code: 200 OK 
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/assets/modeltest.gltf
```

Following a different thread, the cause of a similar problem was that the web server does not serve a glTF but HTML content (https://discourse.threejs.org/t/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-in-json-at-position-0/13810/3). Can the server still be the cause of the problem if I am running the app on local host?

I have tried converting my 3d model into .obj format and then run the OBJLoader. However the same thing happens as the loader attempts to parse HTML when accessing the 'modeltest.obj' file.

Is this failure to load glTF connected to the server Vue is running on localhost when I run `vue-cli-service serve` in terminal? How can I get the glTFLoader to parse my glTF file correctly, not as a HTML?

I have tried loading the glTF file onto this site and it loads correctly https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/

Any advice would be much appreciated. Thank you for reading.

My file structure looks like:

```
3D Model Path:
src/assets/modeltest.gltf
Vue Component Path:
src/components/ThreeTest.vue
```

The code for my Vue component looks like:

```
<template>
    <div id="container"></div>
</template>

<script>
import * as Three from 'three';
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';

export default {
  name: 'ThreeTest',
  data() {
    return {
      camera: null,
      scene: null,
      renderer: null,
      mesh: null,
      model: null,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    init: function() {
      let container = document.getElementById('container');

      this.camera = new Three.PerspectiveCamera(70, container.clientWidth/container.clientHeight, 0.01, 10);
      this.camera.position.z = 1;

      this.scene = new Three.Scene();

      let geometry = new Three.BoxGeometry(0.2, 0.2, 0.2);
      let material = new Three.MeshNormalMaterial();

      this.mesh = new Three.Mesh(geometry, material);
      this.scene.add(this.mesh);

      this.renderer = new Three.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
      this.renderer.setSize(container.clientWidth, container.clientHeight);
      container.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);

      // Instantiate a loader
      var loader = new GLTFLoader();

      // Load a glTF resource
      loader.load(
        // resource URL
        '../assets/modeltest.gltf',
        // called when the resource is loaded
        function ( gltf ) {     
          console.log(gltf);   
          this.scene.add( gltf.scene);
        },
        // called while loading is progressing
        function ( xhr ) {
          console.log( ( xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100 ) + '% loaded' );
        },
        // called when loading has errors
        function ( error ) {
          console.log(error)
          console.log( 'An error happened ' + error );
          
        }
      );
    },
    animate: function() {
        requestAnimationFrame(this.animate);
        this.mesh.rotation.x += 0.01;
        this.mesh.rotation.y += 0.02;
        this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
    }
  },
  mounted() {
      this.init();
      this.animate();
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
 #container{
   height: 100vh;
 }
</style>
```

Comment: Have you checked what the actual contents of the request is? If you go to `http://localhost:8080/assets/modeltest.gltf` with a web browser do you get the file or a HTML page?

Comment: Also usually in Vue static files are served from the `public` folder, not from `src`.

Comment: Thank you for your message. When I go to `http://localhost:8080/assets/modeltest.gltf` I get a HTML page, the Vue app. The canvas renders but without the gltf model (just the box geo)

Comment: I have put a duplicate of the .gltf in the public folder, and specify the path in my component as ('../assets/modeltest.gltf') and still the same error appears.

Comment: Well the file is just in the wrong place. See https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#static-assets-handling and make sure that the URL works (you can download it by accessing the URL directly with a browser). If the file is in the root of the public folder the URLis `http://localhost:8080/modeltest.gltf`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the `modeltest.gltf` in the public folder rather than any other component directory, that would resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the GLTF Loader also needed the license file. Once my loader was able to access the license file along with the .gltf files or the related textures, the error went away